# How to make a Participant Listing menu link in Joomla

Tags: civievent, joomla

Bit of newbie question since we don't work with J! much. This is J! 3.4.3 in case that makes a difference.

I need to make a Participant Listing link. I have enabled it on the civi event, and the instructions there say

> Then create front-end links to the Participant Listing page using the Menu Manager. Select Participant Listing Page and enter 1 for the Event ID.

So I added a Menu, and added a Menu Item which allowed me to set the Menu Item Type to be Participant Listing (from a select) and that added a path in the Link field index.php?option=com_civicrm&view=Events&layout=participantlisting

Looking around for where to add '1' for the Event ID, I find under Options a "select event" but it shows no options in the selector and I have no idea if that is referring to civi events or some other 'concept'. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aaagh - got it. I had done everything right - just my only events were in the past, and hence none showed in the selector.

Comment: You can accept your own answer. That will make it clearer that the question has an answer, for those looking to solve the same problem.

Comment: thx for the reminder and for trawling through v old tickets